# Store data from Entry widget tkinter

Tags: tkinter, python-3.5, tkinter-entry

I'm trying to take the String from an Entry widget and store that to a variable. I'm using a menu item in tkinter to do this I have tried many different things and I still can't get it to work. This is my first python program.

```
 from tkinter import *

 class application(Frame):
   """ A Gui application with three buttons"""

     def __init__(self, master = None):
    """ Inititalization the fram"""
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.master = master
        #self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()



     def create_widgets(self): 

        self.master.title("My GUI")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        buttons1 = Button(self,text = "this wroks", command= self.program_button)
        buttons1.place(x=250,y=250)
        #self.buttons1.place(x=5, y=10)

        menu = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menu)

        test = StringVar()
        eBox = Entry(self, textvariable=test)
        #eBox.pack()
        eBox.grid()



        file = Menu(menu)
        file.add_command(label='Save', command=self.text_capture)
        file.add_command(label='Exit', command=self.program_exit)
        menu.add_cascade(label='File', menu=file)



    def program_button(self):
         exit()

    def program_exit(self):
        exit()
    def text_capture(test):
        #test = StringVar()
        mtext = test.get()
        print(test) # this prints py_Var1 ???
        print(mtext) 
        print(test.get())

root = Tk()

root.geometry("500x500")

app = application(root)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: the reason it prints out py_Var1 is because you are trying to print  a string var instead use a normal variable and var = stringvarname then print(var), I can add code as a post IR it would help

Comment: if not IR autocorrect

Comment: what is a normal variable? I want to capture the string that is entered into the Entry in a tkinter GUI

Comment: a var which isn't varname = StringVar, I'm not at home atm when I am I'll post an answer with some code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed some of your code but on the whole you were pretty close to your wanted end code. The bit i have changed are the following:

```
test = StringVar()
eBox = Entry(self, textvariable=test)
```

to

```
self.test = StringVar()
eBox = Entry(self, textvariable=self.test)
```

and

```
def text_capture(test):
        mtext = test.get()
        print(test)
        print(mtext) 
        print(test.get())
```

to

```
def text_capture(self):
        mtext = self.test.get()
        print(self.test)
        print(mtext) 
        print(self.test.get())
```

The full working code is below:

```
from tkinter import *

class application(Frame):
    """ A Gui application with three buttons"""
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        """ Inititalization the fram"""
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.master = master
        #self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()



    def create_widgets(self):
        self.master.title("My GUI")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        buttons1 = Button(self,text = "this wroks", command= self.program_button)
        buttons1.place(x=250,y=250)
        #self.buttons1.place(x=5, y=10)

        menu = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menu)

        self.test = StringVar()
        eBox = Entry(self, textvariable=self.test)
        #eBox.pack()
        eBox.grid()

        file = Menu(menu)
        file.add_command(label='Save', command=self.text_capture)
        file.add_command(label='Exit', command=self.program_exit)
        menu.add_cascade(label='File', menu=file)



    def program_button(self):
        exit()

    def program_exit(self):
        exit()

    def text_capture(self):
        mtext = self.test.get()
        print(self.test)
        print(mtext) 
        print(self.test.get())

root = Tk()

root.geometry("500x500")

app = application(root)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate it.